# Laravel-api form insert to database

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am making a laravel api with file upload. When uploading file then it gives an error and the form data is not inserted into the database. How can solve this error in laravel please help me.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

         $this->validate($request, [


            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'mobile' => 'required|number|max:10',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $employees = new Detail($request->input()) ;



         $employees->username = $request->get('username'),
         $employees->email= $request->get('email'),
         $employees->mobile = $request->get('mobile'),
         $employees->password = $request->get('password'),

         if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

            $file = $request->file('image') ;

            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
            $employees->image = '/images/'.$fileName ;
        }

         $employees->save();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image Uploaded Successfully']);


    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am resolve this problem. this is my code which working form me.

    public function store(Request $request)

      {

        $details = new Detail($request->input()) ;

         $details->username = $request->username;
         $details->email= $request->email;
         $details->mobile = $request->mobile;
         $details->password = $request->password;

         if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

            $file = $request->file('image') ;

            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
            $details->image = '/images/'.$fileName ;
        }

         $details->save();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image Uploaded Successfully']);

    }
```